# Extremely basic loop question telling whether number is even/odd

Tags: swift, loops, for-loop, int

```
var currentnum: Int = 1

for currentnum in 1...100{
  if (currentnum % 2) != 0 {
    print("Odd number")
  }
  else{
    print("Even number")
  }
  currentnum += 1
}
```

Hello. I'm trying to "create a loop that iterates from 1 to 100 that prints out whether the current number in the iteration is even or odd." When I run the above code, I receive "error: expected expression after operator." What is wrong with my code (I'm new to programming). Thanks!

Comment: "When I run the above code, I receive "error: expected expression after operator."" No, you don't. You do _not_ "run the above code". You cannot run the code because you cannot _compile_ the code: it is invalid Swift. — One problem with your code is that you have _two_ variables called `currentnum`: the one defined in the first line (`var`) and the one defined in the second line (`for`). You need to think about that some more. Hint: `for...in` _already_ increments each time thru the loop, so you do not need the statement `currentnum += 1` at all.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: There's a fancy one liner I can give you that doesn't require a for loop. Are you interested in seeing that?

Comment: @Newbie If you have a good answer give it as an _answer_. Comments are volatile; a useful answer will be useful forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare `var currentnum: Int = 1` in your code and increment through `currentnum += 1`. `for-in` loop does it for you. In Swift `for-in` syntax can be used to loop over both ranges of numbers, collections and even strings. All with the same syntax!

It should be as follows,

```
for currentnum in 1...100{
  if (currentnum % 2) != 0 {
    print("Odd number")
  }
  else{
    print("Even number")
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Unlike some languages you do not need to define the index variable before entering the for-in loop, nor do you need to manually increment the index.

You can also use the new swift function `isMultiple(of:)` rather than `modulus`

If you want to loop through a set range you can do:

```
for num in 1...100 {
    if num.isMultiple(of: 2) {
        print("\(num) is an even number")
    } else {
        print("\(num) is an odd number")
    }
}
```

If you have a set of values in an array you can do this:

```
let numbers = [1,5,12,23,25,27,30,32,35]

for num in numbers {
    if num.isMultiple(of: 2) {
        print("\(num) is an even number")
    } else {
        print("\(num) is an odd number")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of this expression `currentnum += 1`.
Because you are using the In .. [Range](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range) operator there is no need to increment the counter. The In .. Range Operator will take care of this. This is different to the basic for loop from Java or C++ where you need to increment your counter variable.

Additionally the first declared variable currentnum is never used. This variable could be removed too.

The rest of your algorithm looks good and should work!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

One liner without a for loop per the request in the comments

```
Array(1...100).map{$0 % 2 == 0 ? print("\($0) is even") : print("\($0) is odd") }
```

Answer (score -1):

@BeginnerCoderGirl i have changed your code please check just remove currentnum += 1 from code and run

Comment: Thanks for the help!